# Using Python Multiprocessing Queue Inside AWS Lambda Function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, multiprocessing, queue

I have some python that creates multiple processes to complete a task much quicker. When I create these processes I pass in a queue. Inside the processes I use queue.put(data) so I am able to retrieve the data outside of the processes. It works fantastic on my local machine, but when I upload the zip to an AWS Lambda function (Python 3.8) it says the Queue() function has not been implemented.The project runs great in the AWS Lambda when I simply take out the queue functionality so I know this is the only hang up I currently have.

I ensured to install the multiprocessing package directly to my python project by using "pip install multiprocess -t ./" as well as "pip install boto3 -t ./".

I am new to python specifically as well as AWS but the research I have come across recently potentially points we to SQS.

Reading over these SQS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/code-catalog-python-example_code-sqs.html) I am not sure if this is exactly what I am looking for.

Here is the code I am running in the Lambda that works locally but not on AWS. See the *'s for important pieces:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from craigslist import CraigslistForSale
import time
import math

sitesHold = ["sfbay", "seattle", "newyork", "(many more)..." ]

results = []


def f(sites, category, search_keys, queue):
    local_results = []
    for site in sites:
        cl_fs = CraigslistForSale(site=site, category=category, filters={'query': search_keys})
        for result in cl_fs.get_results(sort_by='newest'):
            local_results.append(result)
    if len(local_results) > 0:
        print(local_results)
    queue.put(local_results) # Putting data *********************************


def scan_handler(event, context):
    started_at = time.monotonic()
    queue = Queue()
    print("Running...")
    amount_of_lists = int(event['amountOfLists'])
    list_length = int(len(sitesHold) / amount_of_lists)
    extra_lists = math.ceil((len(sitesHold) - (amount_of_lists * list_length)) / list_length)
    site_list = []
    list_creator_counter = 0
    site_counter = 0
    for i in range(amount_of_lists + extra_lists):
        site_list.append(sitesHold[list_creator_counter:list_creator_counter + list_length])
        list_creator_counter += list_length
    processes = []
    for i in range(len(site_list)):
        site_counter = site_counter + len(site_list[i])
        processes.append(Process(target=f, args=(site_list[i], event['category'], event['searchQuery'], queue,))) # Creating processes and creating queues ***************************

    for process in processes:
        process.start() # Starting processes ***********************

    for process in processes:
        listings = queue.get() # Getting from queue ****************************
        if len(listings) > 0:
            for listing in listings:
                results.append(listing)

    print(f"Results: {results}")

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    total_time_took = time.monotonic() - started_at
    print(f"Sites processed: {site_counter}")
    print(f'Took {total_time_took} seconds long')
```

This is the error the Lambda function is giving me:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 38] Function not implemented",
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/main.py\", line 90, in scan_handler\n    queue = Queue()\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py\", line 103, in Queue\n    return Queue(maxsize, ctx=self.get_context())\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py\", line 42, in __init__\n    self._rlock = ctx.Lock()\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py\", line 68, in Lock\n    return Lock(ctx=self.get_context())\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py\", line 162, in __init__\n    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1, ctx=ctx)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py\", line 57, in __init__\n    sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(\n"
  ]
}
```

Does Queue() work in an AWS Lambda? What is the best way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: For those who are looking for an alternative, this [blog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63633248/15725337) may help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

doesn't look like it's supported -

https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2019/02/19/parallel-processing-on-aws-lambda-with-python-using-multiprocessing/

Comment: Looks like I will be diving into Pipes!

Comment: I ran into the same problem with `multiprocessing.pool`. Unbelievable that this is not supported by AWS.

Answer (score 4):

From the AWS [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/parallel-processing-in-python-with-aws-lambda/)

> If you develop a Lambda function with Python, parallelism doesn’t come
>   by default. Lambda supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.6, both of which
>   have multiprocessing and threading modules.
>
> The multiprocessing module that comes with Python lets you run
>   multiple processes in parallel. Due to the Lambda execution
>   environment not having /dev/shm (shared memory for processes) support,
>   you can’t use multiprocessing.Queue or multiprocessing.Pool.
>
> On the other hand, you can use multiprocessing.Pipe instead of
>   multiprocessing.Queue to accomplish what you need without getting any
>   errors during the execution of the Lambda function.