# Python 3 asyncio with aioboto3 seems sequential

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, async-await, python-asyncio

I am porting a simple python 3 script to AWS Lambda.
The script is simple: it gathers information from a dozen of S3 objects and returns the results.

The script used `multiprocessing.Pool` to gather all the files in parallel. Though `multiprocessing` cannot be used in an AWS Lambda environment since `/dev/shm` is missing.
So I thought instead of writing a dirty `multiprocessing.Process` / `multiprocessing.Queue` replacement, I would try `asyncio` instead.

I am using the latest version of `aioboto3` (8.0.5) on Python 3.8.

My problem is that I cannot seem to gain any improvement between a naive sequential download of the files, and an asyncio event loop multiplexing the downloads.

Here are the two versions of my code.

```py
import sys
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor

import boto3
import aioboto3

BUCKET = 'some-bucket'
KEYS = [
    'some/key/1',
    [...]
    'some/key/10',
]

async def download_aio():
    """Concurrent download of all objects from S3"""
    async with aioboto3.client('s3') as s3:
        objects = [s3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=k) for k in KEYS]
        objects = await asyncio.gather(*objects)
        buffers = await asyncio.gather(*[o['Body'].read() for o in objects])

def download():
    """Sequentially download all objects from S3"""
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    for key in KEYS:
        object = s3.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=key)
        object['Body'].read()

def run_sequential():
    download()

def run_concurrent():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    #loop.set_default_executor(ProcessPoolExecutor(10))
    #loop.set_default_executor(ThreadPoolExecutor(10))
    loop.run_until_complete(download_aio())
```

The timing for both `run_sequential()` and `run_concurrent()` are quite similar (~3 seconds for a dozen of 10MB files).
I am convinced the concurrent version is not, for multiple reasons:

- I tried switching to `Process/ThreadPoolExecutor`, and I the processes/threads spawned for the duration of the function, though they are doing nothing
- The timing between sequential and concurrent is very close to the same, though my network interface is definitely not saturated, and the CPU is not bound either
- The time taken by the concurrent version increases linearly with the number of files.

I am sure something is missing, but I just can't wrap my head around what.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After loosing some hours trying to understand how to use `aioboto3` correctly, I decided to just switch to my backup solution.
I ended up rolling my own naive version of `multiprocessing.Pool` for use within an AWS lambda environment.

If someone stumble across this thread in the future, here it is. It is far from perfect, but easy enough to replace `multiprocessing.Pool` as-is for my simple cases.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from multiprocessing.connection import wait


class Pool:
    """Naive implementation of a process pool with mp.Pool API.

    This is useful since multiprocessing.Pool uses a Queue in /dev/shm, which
    is not mounted in an AWS Lambda environment.
    """

    def __init__(self, process_count=1):
        assert process_count >= 1
        self.process_count = process_count

    @staticmethod
    def wrap_pipe(pipe, index, func):
        def wrapper(args):
            try:
                result = func(args)
            except Exception as exc:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
                result = exc
            pipe.send((index, result))
        return wrapper

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        pass

    def map(self, function, arguments):
        pending = list(enumerate(arguments))
        running = []
        finished = [None] * len(pending)
        while pending or running:
            # Fill the running queue with new jobs
            while len(running) < self.process_count:
                if not pending:
                    break
                index, args = pending.pop(0)
                pipe_parent, pipe_child = Pipe(False)
                process = Process(
                    target=Pool.wrap_pipe(pipe_child, index, function),
                    args=(args, ))
                process.start()
                running.append((index, process, pipe_parent))
            # Wait for jobs to finish
            for pipe in wait(list(map(lambda t: t[2], running))):
                index, result = pipe.recv()
                # Remove the finished job from the running list
                running = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] != index, running))
                # Add the result to the finished list
                finished[index] = result

        return finished
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. Tried this approach, but I get this error:
Can't pickle local object 'Pool.wrap_pipe.<locals>.wrapper'. 
Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

it's 1.5 years later and aioboto3 is still not well documented or supported.

The multithreading option is good. but AIO is an easier and more clear implementation

I don't actually know what's wrong with your AIO code. It's even not running now because of the updates I guess. but using aiobotocore this code worked. my test was with 100 images. in the sequential code, it takes 8 sec. in average. in IO it was less than 2.

with 1000 images it was 17 sec.

```
import asyncio
from aiobotocore.session import get_session
async def download_aio(s3,bucket,file_name):
    o = await s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_name)
    x = await o['Body'].read()

async def run_concurrent(): 
    tasks =[]
    session = get_session()
    async with session.create_client('s3') as s3:
        for k in KEYS[:100]:   
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_object(s3,BUCKET,k)))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```